# Seeking FOSS binary search tree library

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm seeking search tree software for a hobby project.  It needs to support variable-length keys and data and several million items.  It does not need to support deletions so long as the entire tree can be discarded in order to start a new one.  The tree should be balanced.

It would be best if I did not need to use autotools to use it, so that I don't have to learn how to do development in such an environment, at least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late answer, but try to use code from projects:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334773/Graphical-BinaryTrees 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/binarytreeanim/